# Filling an array in parallel with MPI

Tags: c, mpi

I made a root calculator for the Legendre polynomials, and I used a brute force method to find the roots. Since all of the roots are between (-1,1) and they are symmetric, I have a loop from (0,1) and then multiply my array by negative one to get the negative roots. I need to do this in parallel (and I am a novice MPI user) now with MPI and I can not quite get the proper result. When I run it with two processors, it always fills the array of roothalfp with extra zeros and more elements than it should have. I think it is creating two arrays when I run it with two processors. I'm pretty sure there is some sort of bug with the way I used MPI Gather, but I can not figure out exactly what is wrong. At this point I have resorted to just taking in the roothalfp arrays with their extra zeros and attempting to only put the root values (non zero values) into the roothalf array, but I still can not do that properly. Please have mercy on my lack of coding experience.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <mpi.h>

//this is the Legendre polynomial and the degree is specified by the user
double p(int n, double x){
    if(n == 0.){//this is the case for n=0
        return 1.;
    } else if(n == 1.){
        return x;
    }else //this is the case for n>1
    return ((2.*(n-1.)+1)*x*p(n-1.,x)-(n-1.)*p(n-2.,x))/(n);
    //normally this recursive formula looks a bit different, but this one calculates n using n-1 and //n-2
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n;//this is the degree of the Legendre polynomial
    n = atoi(argv[1]);

    if(n>50 || n<=0){
        printf("That's not within the degree of accuracy\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //initializing MPI
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int size;
    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    int start = rank * (1000000 / size); // calculate the start and end values of v for this process
    int end = (rank + 1) * (1000000 / size);

    double *halfroot;
    double *halfrootp;
    if(n % 2 == 1){//when n is odd, zero is always a root and it's never a root when n is even
        halfroot = (double*)malloc(((n+1)/2) * sizeof(double));
        halfrootp = (double*)malloc(((n+1)/2) * sizeof(double));
    } else{ 
        halfroot = (double*)malloc((n/2) * sizeof(double));
        halfrootp = (double*)malloc((n/2) * sizeof(double));
    }
    
    int i = -1;
    //below is the root calculator
    double root[n];//this stores all the roots
        for(int v = start; v<end; v++) {
            double x = v/1000000.0;
            if(p(n,x)*p(n,x+0.000001) < 0) {
            i++;
            halfrootp[i] = x;
    
            }
        }

    //this should combine all of the arrays into one
    MPI_Gather(halfrootp, (n % 2 == 1) ? ((n + 1) / 2) : (n / 2), MPI_DOUBLE, halfroot, (n % 2 == 1) ? ((n + 1) / 2) : (n / 2), MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    int count = 0;
    for(int a=0; a<(n+1)/2; a++){
        if(halfrootp[a] != 0.0){
        halfroot[count]=halfrootp[a];
        count++;
        }
    }

    for(int j=0; j<(n+1)/2; j++){
    printf("half = %lf\n",halfroot[j]);
    }
   
    MPI_Finalize(); // Finalize MPI

    //this fills in the negative roots of the polynomial and 0 if n is odd
    if(n % 2 == 1){    
        for(int j=0; j<(n+1)/2; j++){//not filling in the last elements allows zero to be a root in //the odd array
            root[2*j+1] = -1*halfroot[j];
            root[2*j] = halfroot[j];
        }
    }
    else{//this is the even case
        for(int j=0; j<(n)/2; j++){
            root[2*j]=halfroot[j];
            root[2*j+1]=-1*halfroot[j];
            }
        }
    
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
        printf("root = %lf\n", root[j]);
    }

    free(halfroot);
    free(halfrootp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you only have to allocate `halfroot` on rank `0`. If I understand correctly, you want to concatenete the `halfrootp` that have been found on each rank. Unless there are some mathematical properties I ignore, this should be a two step tangos: `MPI_Gather(&i, ...)` to collect how many `halfrootp` were computed on each rank, and then `MPI_Gatherv(halfroot, i, MPI_DOUBLE, ...) to build the `halfroot` array on rank `0`.

Comment: I basically did that and it works now. I just had to switch from Gather to Allgather and then Gatherv worked as the second step. Thanks so much.

Comment: since the `recvcounts` and `displs` arrays are only relevant on rank `0`, you should not need `MPI_Allgather()`